# AQGridView didSelectItemAtIndex delegate not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, aqgridview

I'm using AQGridView to display images from a web service.  When I touch a cell, the `didSelectItemAtIndex` delegate is not called.  The `numberOfItemsInGridView` delegate is called, so I think I've got my delegates and datasource setup.  Here's the code:

PhotoGridViewController.h

```
#import "AQGridView.h"
#import "PhotoGridViewCell.h"

@interface PhotoGridViewController : UIViewController<AQGridViewDelegate,AQGridViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageDictionaries;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet AQGridView *gridView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet PhotoGridViewCell *gridViewCellContent;

-(void)refreshImages;

@end
```

PhotoGridViewController.m

```
#import "PhotoGridViewController.h"
#import "PhotoGridViewCell.h"
#import "AQGridViewCell.h"

@interface PhotoGridViewController ()
@end

@implementation PhotoGridViewController

@synthesize imageDictionaries = _imageDictionaries;  
@synthesize gridView=_gridView;
@synthesize gridViewCellContent = _gridViewCellContent;
```

...  helpers methods, cell creation, and image fetching methods ...

```
- (NSUInteger) numberOfItemsInGridView: (AQGridView *) aGridView
{
    return ( [self.imageDictionaries count] );
}
```

^^^ This delegate method **is** called ^^^
...

```
-(void)gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSLog (@"Selected theArgument=%d\n", index);
}
```

That NSLog statement is never called.  I used this project  - http://fdiv.net/2011/10/29/reusable-views-ios - as a guide in making mine.  That one works just fine.  I've debugged both and stepped through each step from launch to touching on a cell and I can't find out where I'm going wrong.  Hopefully this is something obvious that I'm just not seeing.

EDIT:  Cells are getting selected because this line

```
cell.selectionStyle = AQGridViewCellSelectionStyleGlow;
```

shows the cell change when it gets touched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the delegate. I bet you forget.

```
self.gridView.delegate = self;
self.gridView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: I KNEW IT!!!! Thanks a ton. I had the dataSource set, but not the delegate.  It's always the simple stuff.